# R markdown/knirt shows old data in HTML document

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have a problem with R markdown. When I knit a document multiple times (because I adapt the code), the knited HTML document is not updated for example are tables (displayed with knitr) old.

Example situation:
I make a analysis with 15 patients and knit the file 5-10x.
Afterwards I ad new 10 patients and knit the same R Markdown file. The new HTML File shows me still the old dataframes with the 15 patients. (I dont know if it is a knitr or R markdown problem).

I tried to clear the output, console and even restart R before knitting. Nothing helped. Even days later when I updated the database and knited the file, it contained the old data.

Has anybody an idea? Thank for your help :)

Comment: Are you enabling caching?  I think it looks for changes in the code, not changes in external data.

Comment: You should try to simplify your document until it does nothing but display the patient count, then see if that updates properly as you change the data.  If so, gradually add things back.  If that doesn't make it clear what's going wrong, then post the smallest version of the document that still shows the issue here.

Comment: This is almost 100% a caching issue. Turn off caching in the knitr options at the start of your document.